# How to copy/clone DbContextOptions<AContext> to a DbContextOptions<BContext>?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

Setting:
One db with many tables, grouped by modules. The moduleTableGroups are independent, there are no relationships in between.

Design:
1: The modules have each there own Context, to keep them small and clear.
2: Because it is an very old Database with manual administration of PKeys and sequences it must be possible to nest SaveChanges, when handling those things in the context.
E.G. AContext has a table with an entity which has a ValueGenerator which reads an incremented value from a table. Because it should be finished before AContext.SaveChanges(), is called, it must be done in an seperate SeqContext in the same db which can handle the concurency issues which might occur.
The SeqContext depends on the DbOptionsContext of AContext.

Wishes:
1: Instead of create Options for each Context which is currently needed, becaus a context seems only to accept context specific options, I'd like to either use the same DbContextOptions for many context or copy or cast the options to a new .

```
DbContextOptions<AContext> aContextOptions = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<AContext>(). . .Options;

// casting:
DbContextOptions<BContext> bContextOptions = (DbContextOptions<BContext>) aContextOptions;

// copy construction:
DbContextOptions<BContext> bContextOptions = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<BContext>(aContextOption).Options;
```

2: Because of the dependency of SeqContext to AContext especially in testing scenarios it would be useful to do something from within a AContext like:

```
SeqContext = new SeqContext((DbContextOptions<SeqContext>) this.getOptions());
```

You might get the idea. How can I archive to share options between different TContext right now?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same case and I dig a little bit into the `DbContextOptionsBuilder` and `DbContextOptions<TContext>` and found a way to do it via the Extensions property of the options object. They are passed and saved when you configure a dbcontext (in my case in ASP.NET Core):

```
// copy the options
var expressions = aContextOptions.Extensions.ToDictionary(x => x.GetType(), x => x);
var copiedOptions = new DbContextOptions<BContext>(new Dictionary<Type, IDbContextOptionsExtension>(expressions));

// test
var objCnt = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(BContext), copiedOptions);
```

**Explanation:**

Each options builders saves the expressions you passed as a configuration in the built options objects in the following collections:

```
IEnumerable<IDbContextOptionsExtension> DbContextOptions<TContenxt>.Extensions
```

On the other hand the `DbContextOptions<TContenxt>` class has a constructor:

```
public DbContextOptions(IReadOnlyDictionary<Type, IDbContextOptionsExtension> extensions)
```

**Usage:**

In my case the DbContextOptions only include setting the connection string and the db driver which I consider universal across DBs. Obviously if one DBContext uses SQL Server and the Other PostgreSQL copying like this will not work.
You can create extensions methods or generic method (`this.getOptions()`) on the a context to return a copy of the current options to match a different context (using the logic above).

**Versions:**

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 6.0.9, ASP.NET Core 6.0